# Sitting up Nginx Reverse Proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have nginx installed on ubuntu 20.4, and I need to set it up as reverse proxy to serve a webserver.

my webserver ip is 192.168.1.13 on port 8089 and I need it to be accessed from the public IP on a url for example webserver.mydomain.com.

my nginx.conf file looks like this:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  webserver.mydomain.com;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $backend;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://192.168.1.13:8089/;
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;
            } # end location
        } # end server
    } # end http
```

is that correct or I have to do something else?

update: when I set hosts file for a local machine with the url and local nginx ip I can access the webserver. but still can't access it from internet ... port forwarded from IPS modem to nginx server ... when I change the forwarding to the webserver I can access it from internet. nginx firewall is disabled.

Comment: Do you have problems with it?

Comment: I can access it as localhost but not from the public IP

Comment: Then provide the error message you encounter, from your client and from the nginx error log.

Comment: This site can’t be reached webserver.mydomain.com took too long to respond.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: Then the issue is most probably a firewall, not your nginx.

Comment: well, I'm testing without firewall direct connection from ISP modem router with port forwarding to the nginx

Comment: To disable the filewall for the port 8089: `sudo ufw allow 8089`.

Comment: Port open, I can access it from local network when I add it to the hosts file but unable to access it from internet, could it be a DNS issue?

Comment: Are you using a DNS provider such as Cloudflare so you can see your domain from the internet? What is the output of `dig webserver.mydomain.com` from a machine other than the server itself?